# Unable to run Cassandra-Stress

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, cassandra-stress

I'm getting below error when running cassandra-stress command

> ./cassandra-stress user
>   profile=/home/cass/apache-cassandra-3.11.2/tools/stress_test.yaml
>   duration=1m "ops(insert=1,latest_event=1,events=1)"

I'm getting the below errors/warnings:

> WARN  18:28:41,488 You listed localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9042 in your
>   contact points, but it wasn't found in the control host's system.peers
>   at startup
>
> Connected to cluster: Test Cluster, max pending requests per
>   connection 128, max connections per host 8
>
> Datatacenter: datacenter1; Host: localhost/127.0.0.1; Rack: rack1
>
> Generating batches with [1..50] partitions and [0..50] rows (of
>   [1..50] total rows in the partitions)
>
> Sleeping 2s...
>
> Warming up insert with 0 iterations... Warming up latest_event with 0
>   iterations...
>
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No query defined with name
>   latest_event
>           at org.apache.cassandra.stress.StressProfile.getQuery(StressProfile.java:362)
>           at org.apache.cassandra.stress.settings.SettingsCommandUser$1.get(SettingsCommandUser.java:93)
>           at org.apache.cassandra.stress.settings.SettingsCommandUser$1.get(SettingsCommandUser.java:82)
>           at org.apache.cassandra.stress.operations.SampledOpDistributionFactory$1.get(SampledOpDistributionFactory.java:83)
>           at org.apache.cassandra.stress.StressAction$Consumer.(StressAction.java:409)
>           at org.apache.cassandra.stress.StressAction.run(StressAction.java:233)
>           at org.apache.cassandra.stress.StressAction.warmup(StressAction.java:121)
>           at org.apache.cassandra.stress.StressAction.run(StressAction.java:70)
>           at org.apache.cassandra.stress.Stress.run(Stress.java:143)
>           at org.apache.cassandra.stress.Stress.main(Stress.java:62)

Here's how my stress_test.yaml  file looks like:

> keyspace: hss_cass_2
>
> table: equipment_status
>
> insert: partitions: uniform(1..50)
>
> batchtype: LOGGED
>
> select: uniform(1..10)/10
>                                      queries:
>
> simple1: cql: select * from equipment_status where equipment_id = ?
>   and eq_status = ? LIMIT 100 fields: samerow
>
> range1: cql: select * from equipment_status where equipment_id = ? and
>   eq_status = ? and equipment_id_type = ? LIMIT 100 fields: multirow

Also, the name of the data center is dc1 but from the error log I find that Datacenter: datacenter1 is given. It might be one of the things which is wrong but I don't know.

Apache Cassandra 3.11.2. RHEL 6.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an error in your command-line - you specified `ops(insert=1,latest_event=1,events=1)`, but you don't have queries with name `latest_event` & `events` - per your file you have only queries `simple1` & `range1` - you need to specify them in the `ops` command...

Following blog posts could provide more information on how to use it: [from the lastpickle](http://thelastpickle.com/blog/2017/02/08/Modeling-real-life-workloads-with-cassandra-stress.html), and this series from instaclustr: [1](https://www.instaclustr.com/deep-diving-into-cassandra-stress-part-1/), [2](https://www.instaclustr.com/deep-diving-into-cassandra-stress-part-2/), [3 (especially this)](https://www.instaclustr.com/deep-diving-cassandra-stress-part-3-using-yaml-profiles/) & [on how to test multiple tables](https://www.instaclustr.com/testing-multiple-tables-cassandra-stress/).